# WeMos D1 R1 show "Hard resetting via RTS pin... " when I upload graghicstest

Tags: arduino

Upload successful, but show me

```
...
TRACE +0.000 Received full packet: 01120200000000000000
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

How can i do it, pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Once it is programmed, the compiler try to reset your device over the RTS (RXD, TXD, RTS) of the serial.

How is your board connected to your computer? Over USB? If it is connected over the USB, there is an hardware error on your USB to Serial converter on the WeMos board (is it a clone?)

What you can do is to manually reset it with the reset button switch on the edge of your board.

If this also does not work, you have to power off and power on again.

The device is already programmed and ready to start, you just need to power off and on (or reset) the module to start your sketch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It's no change when i restart device (power off and power on) or press reset button after upload success and show me 'Hard resetting via RTS pin';

But it's normal when I use example TFT_Touch_Shield_V2 and has not 'Hard resetting via RTS pin' tips after upload, my screen show example text normally.

It well be has problem my device use Adafruit ILI9341?

Comment: It is just an info text... It is to say: "ok, I finished, now I will restart your board". There is a reset line on the D1 R1, it is between the 5V and 3.3V output. If the board can't be reset, maybe you connected something on this pin?

Comment: But nothing dispaly in 2.4' TFT SPI 240*320 screen, and I conntected correct pins borad with TFT.

Comment: There are many factors... Did you connected the reset and the CS pin to your TFT? What kind of controller does your TFT use? Are you using SPI or I2C? Did you used the right library for this controller? There are so many TFTs and so many controllers and so many libraries... You need to post every info about your display, your controller, your library and also your code, if you want more help.